# Finding the derivative 23

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Differentiate $$V= \frac{4\pi r^2}{3}\left(\sqrt{\frac {16}{r^2}-2}\right)$$

I have tried it. But its too complicated for me. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: is this right so?

Comment: Yeah. It is. Sorry Im new to this programming mathjex thing.

Comment: Consider simplifying $\sqrt{\frac{16}{r^2}-2}$ as $\frac{\sqrt{16-2r^2}}{r}$, you can cancel one $r$ then try to apply the product rule.

Comment: Also I wanted to tell you that this site requires that you provide context to your question like why do you want to differentiate this (is this a part of a bigger problem?),what have you tried yourself otherwise your questions might get closed and downvoted.

Comment: To add to kingW3's comment, you should also put a better title than "find the derivative 23"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do $$V^2=\frac {16\pi^2r^4}9\left(\frac{16-2r^2}{r^2}\right)=\frac{32\pi^2}{9}\left(8r^2-r^4\right)$$

Now differentiate both sides wrt $r$

$$2VV'=\frac {32\pi^2}{9}\left(16r-4r^3\right)$$

That simplifies the differentiation part considerably. Now you divide by $2V$ (which you know).

Answer (score 0):

for your first derivative we get by the product and chain rule
$$V'(r)=8/3\,\pi\,r\sqrt {16\,{r}^{-2}-2}-{\frac {64\,\pi}{3\,r}{\frac {1}{
\sqrt {16\,{r}^{-2}-2}}}}
$$
the rule of differentiating is when we have $$f(x)=cg(x)$$, $$f'(x)=cg'(x)$$ if $c$ is a constant

Comment: But when I look back at the answer, it has no pi. That is what confuses me

Comment: but your formula above has a $\pi$!

Comment: dv/dr = 16(4-r^2) / (3rsqrt (16/r^2-2) is the answer

Comment: no this is not right, a $\pi$ is missing

Comment: That is what Im confused about. Do u think the answer scheme is wrong

Comment: yes the answer is definitively wrong

Answer (score 0):

$$V= \frac{4\pi r^2}{3}\left(\sqrt{\frac {16}{r^2}-2}\right)$$
$$V=\frac{4\pi r^2}{3}\left(\sqrt{\frac {16-2r^2}{r^2}}\right)$$
$$V=\frac{4\pi r^2}{3}\cdot\frac {\sqrt{16-2r^2}}{r}$$
$$V=\frac{4\pi }{3}r\sqrt{16-2r^2}$$
$$V'=\frac{4\pi }{3}\left(1\cdot \sqrt{16-2r^2}+r\cdot\frac{-4r}{2\sqrt{16-2r^2}}\right)$$
$$V'=\frac{4\pi }{3}\left(\sqrt{16-2r^2}-\frac{2r^2}{\sqrt{16-2r^2}}\right)$$
$$V'=\frac{4\pi }{3}\frac{16-2r^2-2r^2}{\sqrt{16-2r^2}}=\color{red}{\frac{16\pi}{3}\cdot \frac{4-r^2}{\sqrt{16-2r^2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate it with respect to r first of all note that $\dfrac{4\pi}{3}$ is a constant and that $(a\cdot f(x))'=af(x)$ so, in your case:

$$\dfrac{d}{dr}V=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\sqrt{\dfrac{16}{r^2}-2}\right)$$

So now you just need to apply the product rule $(f\cdot g)'=f'g+fg'$ as follows:

$$\dfrac{d}{dr}V=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\left(2r\sqrt{\dfrac{16}{r^2}-2}+r^2\left(-\dfrac{16\sqrt{r^2}}{r^3\sqrt{16-2r^2}}\right)\right)$$

And, simplifying:

$$\dfrac{d}{dr}V=\dfrac{16\pi r(-r^2+4)}{3r\sqrt{-2r^2+16}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The variable in the problem is $r$, so that’s what we will do the derivative around.

First you’re going to want to write the equation in a more agreeable form:

$$V(r) = \frac{4\pi r^2}{3} \cdot \left(16r^{-2}-2\right)^{1/2}$$

We can see we’re going to need to use the product rule and then also use the chain rule on the righthand side of the multiplication symbol. You can make a substitution to the side, or you can do this all in one fell swoop. I’m going to show you the latter.

First, apply the product rule rule (derivative of the product equals derivative of the first times the second plus the derivative of the second times the first):

$$V'(r) = \frac{d}{dr}\left( \frac{4\pi r^2}{3} \right) \cdot \left(16r^{-2}-2\right)^{1/2} + \frac{4\pi r^2}{3} \cdot \frac{d}{dr} \left[ \left(16r^{-2}-2\right)^{1/2} \right]$$

To evaluate the lefthand derivative, we will want to pull the constant $4\pi/3$ outside the derivative, bring the power of $2$ down in front of the $r$, and reduce the power on $r$ to $1$:

$$V'(r) = \frac{4\pi}{3}(2r) \cdot \left(16r^{-2}-2\right)^{1/2} + \frac{4\pi r^2}{3} \cdot \frac{d}{dr} \left[ \left(16r^{-2}-2\right)^{1/2} \right]$$

To do the righthand derivative, we are going to want to apply the chain rule by doing the derivate (via power rule) *around* $16r^{-2}$ and then multiplying by the derivative of $16r^{-2}-2$:

$$\begin{align}
V'(r) &= \frac{4\pi}{3}(2r) \cdot \left(16r^{-2}-2\right)^{1/2} + \frac{4\pi r^2}{3} \cdot \frac{d}{dr} \left[ \left(\color{blue}{16r^{-2}-2}\right)^{\color{green}{1/2}} \right] \\
V'(r) &= \frac{4\pi}{3}(2r) \cdot \left(16r^{-2}-2\right)^{1/2} + \frac{4\pi r^2}{3} \cdot \color{green}{\frac12}\left(\color{blue}{16r^{-2}-2}\right)^{\color{green}{1/2-1}}\left( \color{blue}{16(-2)r^{-2-1}} \right)
\end{align}$$

From there it’s just algebra.